# Filter a JSON object with forEach

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to drill down to the bottom of this JSON object and find the medication.

This is the JSON

```
const initialState = {
    medicationschedule: [
        {
            date: '2019-08-29',
            medications: [
                {
                    title: '8.00 AM', 
                    id:'1111',
                    data: [
                        {name:'item1', isTaken: 1,mg: '500 mg',capsules:'capsule'}, 
                        {name:'item2', isTaken: 4,mg: '2000 mg',capsules:'teaspoon'}
                ]},
                {
                    title: '12.03 PM', 
                    id:'11112',
                    data: [
                        {name:'item3', isTaken: 2,mg: '500 mg',capsules:'capsule'}, 
                        {name:'item4', isTaken: 1,mg: '500 mg',capsules:'capsule'}
                ]},
                {
                    title: '3.30 PM', 
                    id:'11113',
                    data: [
                        {name:'item1', isTaken: 3,mg: '500 mg',capsules:'capsule'}
                ]},
            ]
        },
        {
            date: '2019-08-26',
            medications: [
                {
                    title: '8.00 AM', 
                    id:'11151',
                    data: [
                        {name:'item1', isTaken: 1,mg: '500 mg',capsules:'capsule'}, 
                        {name:'item2', isTaken: 4,mg: '2000 mg',capsules:'teaspoon'}
                ]},
            ]
        }
    ],
    selectedDate: Date()
};
```

Now I'm using the following function to drill down this object. The function is given below.

```
getMedicationDetail = (medName, groupId) => {
        console.log(medName + " " + groupId + " " + convertedDateString(this.props.selectedDate));
        console.log(typeof(Number(groupId).toString()))

        this.props.medicationschedule.forEach(schedule=>{
            if (schedule.date === convertedDateString(this.props.selectedDate)) {
                  schedule.medications.forEach(medicationsT =>{
                    if (medicationsT.id === groupId) {
                         return medicationsT.data.forEach(medicine => {
                            if( medicine.name === medName ) {
                                console.log(medicine)
                                return medicine
                            }
                        })
                    }
                })
            }
        });
    }
```

The problem is function always returns empty array `[]`. But the line `console.log(medicine)` actually prints the value I want. What could be the root cause of it?

Comment: how are you calling the `getMedicationDetail` function?

Comment: `console.log(this.getMedicationDetail(medName, groupId))` this is how I called it.

Answer (score 4):

You are only returning from the inner callback function of the `forEach` loop, not returning from the `getMedicationDetail` function.

Try something like:

```
getMedicationDetail = (medName, groupId) => {
        console.log(medName + " " + groupId + " " + convertedDateString(this.props.selectedDate));
        console.log(typeof(Number(groupId).toString()))
        let foundMedicine;
        this.props.medicationschedule.forEach(schedule=>{
            if (schedule.date === convertedDateString(this.props.selectedDate)) {
                  schedule.medications.forEach(medicationsT =>{
                    if (medicationsT.id === groupId) {
                         medicationsT.data.forEach(medicine => {
                            if( medicine.name === medName ) {
                                console.log(medicine)
                                foundMedicine = medicine;
                            }
                        })
                    }
                })
            }
        });
        return foundMedicine;
    }
```

Comment: true, and try also to break out the nested loops whenever your expression is true in order not to mess up with your logic.

Comment: You can't break out of a `forEach` loop, would have to use a traditional for loop or write some kind of utility function or exploit `.some` on an array, which doesn't really read well.

Comment: yes indeed maybe using the smell flag way will do the trick or foreach can be changed to a normal for loop for the sake of integrity & performance.

Answer (score 1):

You got empty array because forEach won't receive return value. you should use map instead of forEach if u hope to get return value.

```
// This is wrong, use map instead
schedule.medications.forEach(medicationsT =>{
                    if (medicationsT.id === groupId) {
                         return medicationsT.data.forEach(medicine => {
                            if( medicine.name === medName ) {
                                console.log(medicine)
                                return medicine
                            }
                        })
                    }
                })
```

and i am trying to provide better solution by avoiding the inner loops as much as possible because O<sup>3</sup>, here is my best answer at least it is avoid the O<sup>3</sup> problems:

```
const getMedicationsByDate = initialState.medicationschedule.reduce((prevVal, schedule) => {
    if (schedule.date === "2019-08-29") prevVal.push(schedule.medications)
  return prevVal
}, []).flat(1)

// Get the medicine data only
const getMedicineDataByGroupIdAndName = getMedicationsByDate.reduce((prevVal, medications) => {
    if (medications.id === '11111') {
        const getData = medications.data.filter(({ name }) => name === 'item1')
        prevVal.push(getData)
    }
  return prevVal
},[]).flat(1)

// Get the whole tree of medications object except date
const getWholeMedicationTreeByDate = getMedicationsByDate.map(medication => {
    if (medication.id === '11111') {
      let medic = medication
      medic.data = medication.data.filter(({ name }) => name === 'item1')
      return medic
    }
}).filter(medic => medic)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just push medicine in the array,

```
getMedicationDetail = (medName, groupId) => {
        console.log(medName + " " + groupId + " " + convertedDateString(this.props.selectedDate));
        console.log(typeof(Number(groupId).toString()));
        const medicineList=[];

        this.props.medicationschedule.forEach(schedule=>{
            if (schedule.date === convertedDateString(this.props.selectedDate)) {
                  schedule.medications.forEach(medicationsT =>{
                    if (medicationsT.id === groupId) {
                         medicationsT.data.forEach(medicine => {
                            if( medicine.name === medName ) {
                                console.log(medicine)
                                medicinelist.push(medicine);
                            }
                        })
                    }
                })
            }
        });

        return medicineList;
    }
```

This will return a medicineList. Hope this can help!